# QR code unable to load json file from uri parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am unable to fetch my file from this uri, I have successfully encrypted and decrypted the json file and got it work in the browser but the QRcode is not working.

encoded uri

```
    const encodeduri = encodeURIComponent(
      `{"type":"DOCUMENT","payload":{"uri":"https://absolutesc.com.sg/document/ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1-HCPCR.json","key":"${key}"}}`,
    );
```

Genernate the QRcode

```
    notarisationMetadata: {
        reference: reference,
        notarisedOn: notarisedOn,
        passportNumber: passportNumber,
        url: `https://rinkeby.opencerts.io/?q=${encodeduri}`,
    },
```

the encoded link

https://rinkeby.opencerts.io/?q=%7B%22type%22%3A%22DOCUMENT%22%2C%22payload%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fabsolutesc.com.sg%2Fdocument%2Fffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1-HCPCR.json%22%2C%22key%22%3A%222b1236683c3a842ed4a0bb032c1cf668e24bcaf8ce599aeef502c93cb628152c%22%7D%7D

the decoded link

[https://rinkeby.opencerts.io/?q={"type":"DOCUMENT","payload":{"uri":"https://absolutesc.com.sg/document/ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1-HCPCR.json","key":"2b1236683c3a842ed4a0bb032c1cf668e24bcaf8ce599aeef502c93cb628152c"}}](https://rinkeby.opencerts.io/?q=%7B%22type%22:%22DOCUMENT%22,%22payload%22:%7B%22uri%22:%22https://absolutesc.com.sg/document/ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1-HCPCR.json%22,%22key%22:%222b1236683c3a842ed4a0bb032c1cf668e24bcaf8ce599aeef502c93cb628152c%22%7D%7D)

Encrypt the data

```
   import {
       encryptString,
       decryptString,
       ENCRYPTION_PARAMETERS,
       IEncryptionResults,
       encodeDocument,
       decodeDocument,
    } from "../encryption";

    console.debug("=============== *** ===============");
    const issuedDoc = JSON.stringify(wrappedDocuments);

    const encDoc = encryptString(issuedDoc, key);
    const decDoc = decryptString(encDoc);

    console.debug(encDoc);
    console.debug("===============");
    console.debug(decDoc);

    const ouFileName = 'C:/wamp64/www/document/' + hcpcrJSON;

    console.debug("===============");

    console.log(ouFileName);

    var outputStr = "{" +"\"cipherText\":\"" + encDoc.cipherText + "\"," +
    "\"iv\":\"" + encDoc.iv + "\"," +
    "\"tag\":\"" + encDoc.tag + "\"," +
    "\"type\":\"" + encDoc.type +"\"," +
    "\"ttl\":" + ttl +
    "}";

    console.debug("===============");

    console.log(outputStr);
  
    fs.writeFile(ouFileName, outputStr, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error(err);
    }
  
    console.log("Encrypted Doc written to [" + ouFileName + "] successfully!");
   });
```

Decrypted json file

Pls copy the json file below and drop into this browser, after that just scan the qr code, but it does not work.

```
   {"version":"https://schema.openattestation.com/2.0/schema.json","data":{"id":"5efa8a7b-e749-4025-916b-c52e638a5b46:string:ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1","name":"8d3aeee6-f33f-4f6f-800e-a2c6899f0d31:string:HealthCert","validFrom":"2cf22603-87bc-46f3-8479-caa65e91fedf:string:2021-05-18T06:43:12.152Z","fhirVersion":"09fe41de-d664-4a73-8ce4-cab22f4f34f6:string:4.0.1","fhirBundle":{"resourceType":"44826672-d495-46ac-8969-27a7afcda862:string:Bundle","type":"a43c8cfa-2782-4f53-80e5-76b27361a552:string:collection","entry":[{"resourceType":"8eef06d5-504f-41dd-938d-38cc47c61e9e:string:Patient","extension":[{"url":"d04fa2d3-724e-47c8-a78f-5d7fdd39bdc0:string:http://hl7.org/fhir/StructureDefinition/patient-nationality","code":{"text":"9c814ad1-2435-4056-aa6f-1f9d94d0b580:string:SG"}}],"identifier":[{"type":"32b7eb52-e8a1-45e1-bfe4-71477c245eda:string:PPN","value":"0f2c5f78-f110-4127-acbe-9287083c9ad2:string:E95342203"},{"type":{"text":"3e9a6f07-f847-4d1d-a7af-4a9b9e199b32:string:NRIC"},"value":"d856b4dc-34b9-4ea9-8051-83ec93c7e8b4:string:S9400065J"}],"name":[{"text":"804e6aed-ddea-4d51-ba95-2edf6d0c622b:string:ken Tan"}],"gender":"473c5cce-26c4-4c65-af00-179b115a27ef:string:Male","birthDate":"ee012128-0a94-4eef-8ced-ae0d244971ac:string:1995-01-21T16:00:00.000Z"},{"resourceType":"3054ad1b-9554-4302-824e-0901579b4b09:string:Specimen","type":{"coding":[{"system":"8c726e40-3c76-4702-ac81-52c47ec5a9dd:string:http://snomed.info/sct","code":"0ccac5bd-99d8-4767-9d23-e5f2e8925a8e:string:258500001","display":"4b32dd07-2551-47e6-84c4-5fbe97f78cd0:string:Nasopharyngeal swab"}]},"collection":{"collectedDateTime":"cc1168da-fb1b-444b-87b7-fb987146de6b:string:2022-01-02T16:00:00.000Z"}},{"resourceType":"659c5229-1fd6-4563-af1b-ca63fb57b211:string:Observation","identifier":[{"value":"123e9b24-e3a4-444a-873a-919ccbaf6d21:string:123456789","type":"d47a1b9b-b5a3-43bc-acf0-d700ccad8fbc:string:ACSN"}],"code":{"coding":[{"system":"d533c509-a082-4874-95bd-62af059b88ac:string:http://loinc.org","code":"25d81010-3d29-4291-a496-ec250764e0fb:string:94531-1","display":"30a039cb-26bd-474b-ad90-47e7b4c5d3fc:string:Reverse-transcription-polymerase-chain-reaction-(rRT-PCR)-test"}]},"valueCodeableConcept":{"coding":[{"system":"c292d28a-bb22-4896-a2ef-946f2f8de76d:string:http://snomed.info/sct","code":"52d17ea2-86d3-4794-9596-8c9a30d1134f:string:260385009","display":"820b2b2c-9fa4-443f-9a87-5e4a7dac070e:string:Negative"}]},"effectiveDateTime":"9229826d-ce2e-44b7-9ceb-db104f12b3d6:string:2022-01-02T16:00:00.000Z","status":"0a6fdee7-8a6c-47d5-9114-221101739234:string:final","performer":{"name":[{"text":"3615c182-e50b-4af0-995c-cb6535dd45b8:string:Dr Michael Lim"}]},"qualification":[{"identifier":"37177552-c945-4b92-a2ed-10293d8cd68e:string:MCR-013-210614B","issuer":"f742dc95-f14e-49a6-83a2-5abdc5d3ba56:string:MOH"}]},{"resourceType":"cb4d6ead-9927-4df0-a5e3-31d8902387c1:string:Organization","name":"a6b753df-d651-4507-9af4-c3d43dd4d9bc:string:MacRitchie Medical Clinic","type":"d8bb477c-067a-4fbb-a0aa-c37f930fbe13:string:Licensed Healthcare Provider","endpoint":{"address":"666c0542-6b35-484e-a7d2-8475021753fd:string:https://www.macritchieclinic.com.sg"},"contact":{"telecom":[{"system":"d5ee8d2b-b2f6-4041-bb38-2866954090af:string:phone","value":"87c60213-a9df-48f6-a9ea-09fb7370ae79:string:6563113111"}],"address":{"type":"efad3572-8d68-444f-b9d6-174a4f71a38f:string:physical","use":"1752dcbd-d987-4d3b-af33-aad94a61d513:string:work","text":"d446a3a9-2ba1-4d4d-8b8e-382954879ddd:string:MacRitchie Hospital Thomson Road Singapore 123000"}}},{"resourceType":"8c37c940-d1af-46fd-8ed5-c9d339ccab20:string:Organization","name":"28732b61-7fc8-464f-9cac-a774f59347e4:string:MacRitchie Laboratory","type":"eaf936c1-7ec9-4b52-b702-4eadc08377e7:string:Accredited Laboratory","contact":{"telecom":[{"system":"6e704655-fad0-4c38-ba6e-e5023a676ce9:string:phone","value":"fec2ff19-7ba4-48c5-b397-3a37c950210f:number:6562711188"}],"address":{"type":"8f86a0ab-11ec-4cc1-9f2b-68ae7fe78fe3:string:physical","use":"c6d48a80-7218-4d03-8696-eb4ddf700163:string:work","text":"db3301f4-ebb7-418c-bf50-a8305efe5f79:string:2 Thomson Avenue 4 Singapore 098888"}}}]},"transcriptId":"05482c97-6461-47f7-8a85-37490563d195:string:298","patientId":"b786beba-eba9-4c80-b8c4-18e488ef1d02:string:H00051","patientEmail":"966f4ab7-0de4-44f0-99dd-be0998d2ca51:string:ken@hotmail.com","patientFirstName":"700c40ec-ef42-4583-bc79-97647bf953a9:string:ken","patientLastName":"0a88194c-a518-43ee-aa7b-35c432402e57:string:Tan","reference":"9c916df7-c2f2-4e57-91fd-058b2d0e0c3a:string:ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1","title":"b8d94343-de11-43da-9953-5df67f341463:string:RRT-PCR TEST","notarisedOn":"59e21df1-833b-471d-8ee4-49ce99f3a41b:string:2021-05-21T06:29:14.216Z","passportNumber":"01be35f6-a430-45cd-8b95-9a6b73285343:string:E95342203","issuers":[{"name":"16df0c8f-a07e-4e25-ae53-91a11459e5c4:string:JEDTrade","documentStore":"9234f1f9-a0d2-43ee-a2de-a11dfcd5c944:string:0x8Cb6F104C7943bcA3D109699c4748F53583F17EA","identityProof":{"type":"e49adab8-5518-42f1-a068-f21c13df16dd:string:DNS-TXT","location":"6080187e-b3f2-44f4-912d-4c101c351dbc:string:fresh-apricot-gayal.sandbox.openattestation.com"}}],"$template":{"name":"be1d7106-6d89-4d3e-8127-47c904a4837f:string:HEALTH_CERT","type":"969a44c2-6e01-4225-9ca2-178c11cf45b7:string:EMBEDDED_RENDERER","url":"8beb523b-7f45-4562-a729-f441f65f46ac:string:https://healthcert.renderer.moh.gov.sg/"},"notarisationMetadata":{"reference":"604eb5ac-3c22-40d7-a155-ca0af1253c1d:string:ffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1","notarisedOn":"65aac206-498e-4575-998f-edc5be2fbeef:string:2021-05-21T06:29:14.216Z","passportNumber":"6e947e47-c955-418b-8deb-1765dfe3b16f:string:E95342203","url":"bedd6ed8-5e1d-4c26-8b6a-127f5d9b3b9f:string:https://rinkeby.opencerts.io/?q=%7B%22type%22%3A%22DOCUMENT%22%2C%22payload%22%3A%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fabsolutesc.com.sg%2Fdocument%2Fffb1e61f-30ec-419c-9e0c-baa844d876b1-HCPCR.json%22%2C%22key%22%3A%222b1236683c3a842ed4a0bb032c1cf668e24bcaf8ce599aeef502c93cb628152c%22%7D%7D"},"logo":"bbb3ba1d-9e37-4548-bf21-28cffc4bdd97:string:data:image/png;base64,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","attachments":[{"filename":"65f09b37-27d0-4a3f-b6ca-3e8a1b7ea679:string:healthcert.txt","type":"f8d3553d-1476-4456-a41d-35916e394f0a:string:text/open-attestation","data":"114b109b-212f-4933-866b-1dca76aa229a:string:eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zY2hlbWEub3BlbmF0dGVzdGF0aW9uLmNvbS8yLjAvc2NoZW1hLmpzb24iLCJkYXRhIjp7ImlkIjoiOWJhZjQ4MWQtNjJjNy00NjEzLWE2MGYtYmM4ZTljMjk3NjQwOnN0cmluZzpURVNUMDAxIiwibmFtZSI6IjYxYWM0ZTY3LWQ5ZDgtNDMyMi1iYWI4LWE5MTI4ZjBjY2ZhZDpzdHJpbmc6SGVhbHRoQ2VydCIsInZhbGlkRnJvbSI6IjM1NTc3NTg0LTk3NDAtNDRjOC1iMDdiLThhMzU0NTkyMDNhMDpzdHJpbmc6MjAyMS0wNS0xOFQwNjo0MzoxMi4xNTJaIiwiZmhpclZlcnNpb24iOiI5ODQ2M2NjNC1mNGViLTQxN2QtOTY1ZC05MzUxMjBkOTFmMGU6c3RyaW5nOjQuMC4xIiwiZmhpckJ1bmRsZSI6eyJyZXNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiI3ZGViN2QwOS1kNmIyLTRlMDMtOGY1Yy04MTE4NGViNzYyNWE6c3RyaW5nOkJ1bmRsZSIsInR5cGUiOiI0Y2ZmOTAyMy0xYjdlLTRkODEtYjJhNS03M2UzOGM4Zjg5N2U6c3RyaW5nOmNvbGxlY3Rpb24iLCJlbnRyeSI6W3sicmVzb3VyY2VUeXBlIjoiZDFlOGUwMWItN2Q5MS00ZDI5LWIyMzgtYTkzNWYwMjIyZmY3OnN0cmluZzpQYXRpZW50IiwiZXh0ZW5zaW9uIjpbeyJ1cmwiOiI1YmUwNGI1Zi0wMzkwLTQxZmItOGFmOC01NmY5MGM0Mzg3NmM6c3RyaW5nOmh0dHA6Ly9obDcub3JnL2ZoaXIvU3RydWN0dXJlRGVmaW5pdGlvbi9wYXRpZW50LW5hdGlvbmFsaXR5IiwiY29kZSI6eyJ0ZXh0IjoiYmYzNDA3YmMtNjU1Mi00YzhiLWI5YzItYzc2YTRmOGU1OTRlOnN0cmluZzpTRyJ9fV0sImlkZW50aWZpZXIiOlt7InR5cGUiOiI4OTZmZjc1Ni03ODY0LTQyYjQtYTQ1Ny1mMjNlM2U5MTZkNmY6c3RyaW5nOlBQTiIsInZhbHVlIjoiMjY0OGNhOGItYWE2Yy00M2I4LTlhMWItYjU1NDg0MGEyN2Q0OnN0cmluZzpFNzgzMTE3N0cifSx7InR5cGUiOnsidGV4dCI6ImUxYzMxY2RiLTdmMTEtNGRlNy1hZTZjLWE2MTk2NmIyYWVhZDpzdHJpbmc6TlJJQyJ9LCJ2YWx1ZSI6IjJhNDVjZDFhLTQzOTUtNGVjMS1hM2EzLWUzNGY0NjdiMzBhYzpzdHJpbmc6UzkwOTg5ODlaIn1dLCJuYW1lIjpbeyJ0ZXh0IjoiZTk0OTIxNzctZDg3ZC00NzU1LTk5YWQtNTk3ZjRjOTFjZGI3OnN0cmluZzpUYW4gQ2hlbiBDaGVuIn1dLCJnZW5kZXIiOiI3YmMxNTY1My1hMjJmLTQyMmEtODk3ZS01ZjA2NzI4MjdhYjI6c3RyaW5nOmZlbWFsZSIsImJpcnRoRGF0ZSI6IjA4NGZhNGE3LTAzZTQtNDJmYS1iMDQwLTYyNjk4ZTVjNjIwODpzdHJpbmc6MTk5MC0wMS0xNSJ9LHsicmVzb3VyY2VUeXBlIjoiYzZkNmVjNmEtZjIzNi00OWY3LWJmYjktN2Y4NTVhN2FkNDI1OnN0cmluZzpTcGVjaW1lbiIsInR5cGUiOnsiY29kaW5nIjpbeyJzeXN0ZW0iOiIwZjFiMWE3OS00MzJhLTQ1OTEtOWM1YS1iNWZlZmNkMjVkNTA6c3RyaW5nOmh0dHA6Ly9zbm9tZWQuaW5mby9zY3QiLCJjb2RlIjoiYmExMzJjZDktZTkyNy00OTM4LWE3MDQtYmNlMWQ0NzdjZDgzOnN0cmluZzoyNTg1MDAwMDEiLCJkaXNwbGF5IjoiZmRhMmU4MTYtNzc0Mi00ZDQzLWI2OTctNTFiNzRkOGZmNDhlOnN0cmluZzpOYXNvcGhhcnluZ2VhbCBzd2FiIn1dfSwiY29sbGVjdGlvbiI6eyJjb2xsZWN0ZWREYXRlVGltZSI6IjI0MzRjMDIyLTA0NDctNGFmMS05YWMzLWU0ZjMzOWU3NzZjODpzdHJpbmc6MjAyMC0wOS0yN1QwNjoxNTowMFoifX0seyJyZXNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiI3ODc1NjlmNy1iMGJmLTRmYWMtYWY3My1hNjhlYmExMjk4NWU6c3RyaW5nOk9ic2VydmF0aW9uIiwiaWRlbnRpZmllciI6W3sidmFsdWUiOiI1NjIzYzk3My1hYmE1LTQyM2UtYWUyZi1jOTRlZmRhODkyNGQ6c3RyaW5nOjEyMzQ1Njc4OSIsInR5cGUiOiI1Mjg0ZTJhMS0wMTYzLTQwNTktOWNlYS1mNTk3NzlkZmJkMGI6c3RyaW5nOkFDU04ifV0sImNvZGUiOnsiY29kaW5nIjpbeyJzeXN0ZW0iOiJlNmIxZjNjMS1lN2U1LTQ2ZTktYTM3Mi1mYjliNmFjYjc1MGQ6c3RyaW5nOmh0dHA6Ly9sb2luYy5vcmciLCJjb2RlIjoiZjJiYWVlODUtMThhYi00YzMyLWJlZTItMTRlNzUzZjNiYmY2OnN0cmluZzo5NDUzMS0xIiwiZGlzcGxheSI6ImMxMzE4ZjkyLTc4YzUtNDM3OC1iZTg4LTE4NzQ2YjFhZDM0ODpzdHJpbmc6UmV2ZXJzZSB0cmFuc2NyaXB0aW9uIHBvbHltZXJhc2UgY2hhaW4gcmVhY3Rpb24gKHJSVC1QQ1IpIHRlc3QifV19LCJ2YWx1ZUNvZGVhYmxlQ29uY2VwdCI6eyJjb2RpbmciOlt7InN5c3RlbSI6IjkyMTA3NGE1LTQ2OGYtNGVkMC04MGUyLTMyNmM5ODA5OTJmYzpzdHJpbmc6aHR0cDovL3Nub21lZC5pbmZvL3NjdCIsImNvZGUiOiI4NmFjNDk2ZS00MmI0LTRjMmMtOWZjMy0xNGNiZjUzYTQyYjI6c3RyaW5nOjI2MDM4NTAwOSIsImRpc3BsYXkiOiI4YjA2OWYzOC1iZTQyLTRkYmYtYWVlOS0yNTRjOWVjNGM0ODM6c3RyaW5nOk5lZ2F0aXZlIn1dfSwiZWZmZWN0aXZlRGF0ZVRpbWUiOiI3MWM1ZjM5Yy03YmE2LTRjYzUtYjkxOS03Zjk5ZDgyOTA1ZjQ6c3RyaW5nOjIwMjAtMDktMjhUMDY6MTU6MDBaIiwic3RhdHVzIjoiNGUyMjZkNDMtZTNmMi00YWExLTk4NzItMWEyYmMzZDdlZGE4OnN0cmluZzpmaW5hbCIsInBlcmZvcm1lciI6eyJuYW1lIjpbeyJ0ZXh0IjoiMzNjNmYzZTQtOGY0ZS00NmFkLWJlNzMtY2FmYjNmZTI3YTI5OnN0cmluZzpEciBNaWNoYWVsIExpbSJ9XX0sInF1YWxpZmljYXRpb24iOlt7ImlkZW50aWZpZXIiOiI3Yzg0NjUzZC00YjYzLTRhMjUtODJhZS1lOGUyNjE3NjQ2ZTk6c3RyaW5nOk1DUiAxMjMyMTQiLCJpc3N1ZXIiOiIxNzk4YmVkNC1kY2FjLTQwNmYtOTQyOC05NTgyMDVjYzk1MzU6c3RyaW5nOk1PSCJ9XX0seyJyZXNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiJkN2E5MDMzNy0xYTdhLTRkNWQtYTAzZC03Nzk0ZTE1ZmQ3ODk6c3RyaW5nOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIsIm5hbWUiOiI1YTFhOTExNC1kZWE3LTQ2MGItYWNiZS04NWFmNjEzNzNmY2E6c3RyaW5nOk1hY1JpdGNoaWUgTWVkaWNhbCBDbGluaWMiLCJ0eXBlIjoiYWU0YmU1M2QtYzU0Yi00NzZhLWI1NTgtOWM5ZjE3NDk2N2ZmOnN0cmluZzpMaWNlbnNlZCBIZWFsdGhjYXJlIFByb3ZpZGVyIiwiZW5kcG9pbnQiOnsiYWRkcmVzcyI6IjU4NTFjODY0LTA1ZTItNDYxZi05MTBhLTc0Y2FhOWNiNDQ5YjpzdHJpbmc6aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cubWFjcml0Y2hpZWNsaW5pYy5jb20uc2cifSwiY29udGFjdCI6eyJ0ZWxlY29tIjpbeyJzeXN0ZW0iOiJmYzliZWQwYS1hYTNmLTQyMjUtYTdmYS00MzU5ZTJiNDAxMjQ6c3RyaW5nOnBob25lIiwidmFsdWUiOiJlOTZjZWEwNy0yZjE5LTQyMDMtOTg4ZC0zNzUwMjM3N2E3ZTU6c3RyaW5nOis2NTYzMTEzMTExIn1dLCJhZGRyZXNzIjp7InR5cGUiOiIwYTQ5OTA5Ni1jNDRkLTRkMmEtYmJkYi03ODM0YjI5ZjQ2ZGU6c3RyaW5nOnBoeXNpY2FsIiwidXNlIjoiOTQ5ZTUxM2QtYThmMS00ZWVlLTkwOWEtMDhjZTBlMWI3NDllOnN0cmluZzp3b3JrIiwidGV4dCI6IjQ5ODZiMTRmLWViODUtNDdhMy1iNzRlLTYxMWFmZDg0ZWUxZTpzdHJpbmc6TWFjUml0Y2hpZSBIb3NwaXRhbCBUaG9tc29uIFJvYWQgU2luZ2Fwb3JlIDEyMzAwMCJ9fX0seyJyZXNvdXJjZVR5cGUiOiI4YTE4MmQ5YS1hMDZhLTQ0MDItOWMyOC02YjQzMTRiZjY5ODU6c3RyaW5nOk9yZ2FuaXphdGlvbiIsIm5hbWUiOiJhMjZjNTY5NC0xYjg3LTRlMDItYmJlYi0wY2ZiYTM2YmM4ODc6c3RyaW5nOk1hY1JpdGNoaWUgTGFib3JhdG9yeSIsInR5cGUiOiIzMTdkZDJiNS02YThhLTQwZGItODM4Yi0zNDc5ZmVjZDM0NTI6c3RyaW5nOkFjY3JlZGl0ZWQgTGFib3JhdG9yeSIsImNvbnRhY3QiOnsidGVsZWNvbSI6W3sic3lzdGVtIjoiMjc1ZDYwYjUtOTk1OC00ZGJjLTg1MzUtZjExMDVjNDJhNjVmOnN0cmluZzpwaG9uZSIsInZhbHVlIjoiMjVjYTE3ODEtMDhkMS00NmYyLWFmZDUtZWUwY2U5OTExY2YzOnN0cmluZzorNjU2MjcxMTE4OCJ9XSwiYWRkcmVzcyI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiZTNmMGFkODQtZDFjMC00MDM4LTk1ZTctNGRlYzQ3YWY2ZmJjOnN0cmluZzpwaHlzaWNhbCIsInVzZSI6ImE1Yjg3ZGU0LTgyMjQtNDU0Zi1iNThkLWUyYWZkMzA5OGI2MTpzdHJpbmc6d29yayIsInRleHQiOiI0ODM4M2Q3MC1jNmU2LTRkNjUtYmRjMi03YTU0MjNjM2IyMWE6c3RyaW5nOjIgVGhvbXNvbiBBdmVudWUgNCBTaW5nYXBvcmUgMDk4ODg4In19fV19LCJpc3N1ZXJzIjpbeyJpZCI6IjZlNTdkYzZhLTRlZWEtNGE1NC04OTg2LWFkZWVhNzExZTEwMzpzdHJpbmc6ZGlkOmV0aHI6MHhFMzk0Nzk5MjhDYzRFZkZFNTA3NzQ0ODg3ODBCOWY2MTZiZDRCODMwIiwicmV2b2NhdGlvbiI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiMDM2Nzc5MGQtNjQzYy00YTA2LWJkYjMtNjM4YmZkMjE2Yzk4OnN0cmluZzpOT05FIn0sIm5hbWUiOiI3MDQ0OTljMC02ZjM4LTRjZmQtODQxMC0wM2Q0N2UyNDA1ZTY6c3RyaW5nOlNBTVBMRSBDTElOSUMiLCJpZGVudGl0eVByb29mIjp7InR5cGUiOiI5OWM4MTQwNy05MmI0LTRhMDctODFkMC0wZDdjZDc3YTJhNWM6c3RyaW5nOkROUy1ESUQiLCJsb2NhdGlvbiI6ImQwMGRhYjhmLTJmM2EtNDE4Mi05ODAyLWRmMDE1ZGM2YmIwYjpzdHJpbmc6ZG9ub3R2ZXJpZnkudGVzdGluZy52ZXJpZnkuZ292LnNnIiwia2V5IjoiMmNiMDA1NjEtOGJhNy00MTI4LWExYzMtMTdlMGRmZjBkZDgwOnN0cmluZzpkaWQ6ZXRocjoweEUzOTQ3OTkyOENjNEVmRkU1MDc3NDQ4ODc4MEI5ZjYxNmJkNEI4MzAjY29udHJvbGxlciJ9fV0sImxvZ28iOiJmZmRhZTk0MS1iNmUwLTQyYzctOTJhMS0yOGE3Mjg1NGU3ZDQ6c3RyaW5nOmRhdGE6aW1hZ2UvcG5nO2Jhc2U2NCxpVkJPUncwS0dnb0FBQUFOU1VoRVVnQUFBZlFBQUFESUNBTUFBQUFweCtQYUFBQUFNMUJNVkVVQUFBRE16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXpNek16TXplQ21pQUFBQUFFSFJTVGxNQVFMK0E3eEFnbjJEUDN6QndyMUNQRWwrSS9RQUFCd2RKUkVGVWVOcnNuZDEyMnlvUVJ2a0hJU0hOK3ovdHlVazlvVEVDUTFiVEJjMjNieU5zMEI1R0lEQVJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBaytJaytJZHg0ZzVONEI5R1EvclBBOUovSVBmU2d3TC9NRUVBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBRHdQNVpQb1A1cjdGSktBZjdjdWZCaWhQTlNrWDVobEE5dStEc1A3ZFgvSksxUDJWUGlTSW9lYkVyTHdWaDVaeCs4QzFZMjJZdFAwRnBmNmhkZWErbXExV2xpeGZlajZSY0R4ajA5c3dYYmJlQlFwaWp1ZzIwYWovU0U4YnZvNWhFdWF2QXVTS3BRZkp4VEc5MWdVckNWNmpTUUUwb1BrZTR3dWtlNzA1RXFwTE5XeHRNdFNrNGp2WEdsZCt0TGx4dlZNTm5ha0Q3bUVuZFlUVldTblY4NjBXVVhsMzRSTXk3QmVtcHlHek43cEFibVhFQTZiZnZLMHUzMnVURktLVk0wcjBZdzFNVGNGdnA4aVZMUEQwKzlnSFF5KzdyU2YzZWVqcDJIdUZjc21sZGlFejBGektYZlNSdzNxZTA4WHFkOWRQNlFLT05ua3U0bEczTlNiL1JCdEt0S3QxdHRkQkppWWIyVkk3YnJjN3RjOElZb3RKekhVQjBjK08rVDNyVFF1TEtzWlJxcHprVFM3ZFpJNHZvK3FKbmRFR084RXplY3lqYWM2L0lUTjJLT1dhVUxJVC9hTGRlVW5xcGRpN1ZXMitLeWMyOUZMM3M3ZTNoaTVMVFNoZVdXcHlXbEg0WHptdldqbmlPaUZOM1lXRGl2V0k5Mld1azVjdDJDMHAzSnpsOVlONjZXSTVJVi9WeUY4NnIxYTE3cEg1VU1DMHBYL0R3WFZVNTI0S3M1WWdEWm1MNHpHejF3ODBwMzNQajFwTXZjaSt0YzJjRklqbWhIMmRXVmZ1YVZMdUxqeTllVHpncU9ycWV3djB2dW0vMUtSNCsyYTZEaDVwWE83VjlPK3M0S1JKUEFEdXhOanRqRkNDay9DbHRFemdmelN0ZXJTdmRaUVplRG95eXF4UWd1UjFsWG1CbEkvOVBTZWJacGJPZThiaXZ0MmJGSzlZYUs0ZUhlN05MTmF0TFAzcUdZTGZMNzFSb012QjZYdTk2SjNUV3Q5TFRvUU01em04WWZ4YkhJRVNQWlhYVy90b3ZUU28rUHFGeE5lc3dacWpPL1gwOU92QmdpOU9jSHc3bGxVdWtjditkaTBybmVxZjk5dVhvS2dsTU13YWxsN3gvbXkwbWxQNXBpVm52M2Z1WisxOTN4bnBUWUx6M1NqZWpQTFhwTzZUdFhielhwZklVY2VKSG1Qc1hBSnNiSSthTDdmdnNwcFZzT1g3dWFkSjlGdnVUNjNQeHNaQVEzVU14eWdMeVd2c2s2L2x1a3U0MGZiOHR0b2xERkZiMVpRUTYvbVJrdjFpVzlpMUo2Qy8xYWVqQWN2UVBWbVV0NkZCMmNuMjZKekRPNFRzYUxjV2VhVGJvN0luMDRYMDg2OTZYeFRucmttekdDSGltbUpwTHVOYVBpNzFmK0tPa3RlNUlLOU9yUzc0aW5nUFNmSmQxb0lTRDlaMG0vaFBoQjBvKy9MZDNNTUdVclNVNjhzOXlVelhTTzNzdWhXK0JoK0pqMG95ejJzblpxZ3BjemQ1aXdwdlJ2bUtmWHBZL1AweWVTZnNnSE9obGl3dExTN2NCU2lSMWFaRlAzMHErQnQzZlhiSzloUTJUcis0clNjKzhkZmxYQ08ybDZwWStQSXM1cEYxeHM0a21iWFZCNnowSldSUmRIKzZCMHc4VmVveWRlV2xWODR4YVVMbnZYMDh2RXpObitISk91K3RmVDFjU2JLUExld3ZXa2MvYzEvWXRzNFNsSitESHB1bnNGMzA2OVhTcnc3VmhRZWw0Z0hOM1F1SE84akVrL084Y0MrVW8vcFhSK3ZHMExTbi9aWHhsWHlJb2M2MFBTaGVsZHd2ZHpiNEhXM0k3MXBPLzB3SFlxT0lwOHY0MUpUNTJUTmpmNWp4MjRmbUU5NldMckc3L2Jzb002ZWhDR3BKOHMwL1pWM2s4cW5UT2RYMUI2NkhPZ2I0YjVLUmZ0bDU0ZkM3b3Z5dlpacFh0Nkp5NG8zWnFlZE92TVRkc2xQVWhEMHJsV3h2Vk1GdFMwUDFVT25QdldrODRYZGIwRElYVy9rSGlNU0xlbTdyTU1LRG10OUowSG1ndEsvM0JnN0doZ09HTENnUFQ4YWZwMXBkVEV4NDg4Nm5ndEtGMmM5T3BzZ1ZEYk9LQ0pPUWFraSsxVnJGaSt3cmlKcGZOYS9vclNoY3JXMjg2akxZc3l5ZlpMbDhTRXRuTTY1ajFTTEgrd1hWRzZqYzBEWUk5ODZGdWpLSm5RTFYwYzFNcnc3c081bi9md3dEZmtvajlnZkQ0b3poeUZBVVZNcUJSbFlyQ2Qwb1VuUnJraXlFek9QRk5MRnpUelQ1VmxCWGQzT204b3prQnRPT2REUFprVTlrOS9QQ3BMa0hhcm5aVWZJaFhPdjAvNklTdjBTT2N2ai8xYjl0emZrTjVHM3g3ZWJkSWgzNFdmRjZ0cERycllLNlBVcGQvNGZKUzNicFhhcnRPSk4rU1JEQlhPdjBsNm02RXpaMXozNWx3OWszUk8wMVdNRkJVNEg0KzIxbE1iYjhYczB2bHZZVkhwM1BVcUtDY2FPRFVzbmJOTFNSNWNUQytkWitwcFZlbENuS2ExMTdlTlROUWtTVkZpVTJ0UCtRclNPVnZaWmFVTHF3dnRQQ2gvamRNYjNSTjk5UU9rb2p2OExzUVMway9PNyt0S2YrTk1UOTZOUDBVdkx2aW5SbTlKbjI0d1ZyYkRDYkdJZEY0eFZCTkoveEpTZTZVZW8vQmovOUkvN0R5MFB2cm5KeTVvcFNJUlJaWDBhUVVBQVB6WDNoM1VBQUNBUUF4N1lBRC9hbkZCQ05kYW1JQUJBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQURBbW1vZUs5SHppQjVJOUVCWG54OEFBQUFBQUFBQUFMQm1BSVpLbXpXSW54eU9BQUFBQUVsRlRrU3VRbUNDIiwiJHRlbXBsYXRlIjp7Im5hbWUiOiI1NjhhNjdiNC0zNzhjLTQ5MjgtYjNhNi05NDc2ZDcxYjBhOWU6c3RyaW5nOkhFQUxUSENFUlQiLCJ0eXBlIjoiMWZlNTlmNmMtODhlNC00MTUzLTg1NjgtMzAwOTU5ZDZiNzlhOnN0cmluZzpFTUJFRERFRF9SRU5ERVJFUiIsInVybCI6ImZhZThkMGJkLTExMWQtNGNjNC1hZGUzLWYyMDhlMjRhNTFiOTpzdHJpbmc6aHR0cHM6Ly9tb2gtaGVhbHRoY2VydC1yZW5kZXJlci5uZXRsaWZ5LmFwcC8ifX0sInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiU0hBM01lcmtsZVByb29mIiwidGFyZ2V0SGFzaCI6IjBjOTIwYTEzNmZhODc3YjkzMzNmYjYyOWFjNmY2YjU0ZTAyODc5OWY2NzVkNTAxYjE3YzM1MjVlZGY1NDZkZDEiLCJwcm9vZiI6W10sIm1lcmtsZVJvb3QiOiIwYzkyMGExMzZmYTg3N2I5MzMzZmI2MjlhYzZmNmI1NGUwMjg3OTlmNjc1ZDUwMWIxN2MzNTI1ZWRmNTQ2ZGQxIn0sInByb29mIjpbeyJ0eXBlIjoiT3BlbkF0dGVzdGF0aW9uU2lnbmF0dXJlMjAxOCIsImNyZWF0ZWQiOiIyMDIxLTA1LTE5VDAzOjA5OjQxLjIyN1oiLCJwcm9vZlB1cnBvc2UiOiJhc3NlcnRpb25NZXRob2QiLCJ2ZXJpZmljYXRpb25NZXRob2QiOiJkaWQ6ZXRocjoweEUzOTQ3OTkyOENjNEVmRkU1MDc3NDQ4ODc4MEI5ZjYxNmJkNEI4MzAjY29udHJvbGxlciIsInNpZ25hdHVyZSI6IjB4NzMwOTFlZjE2MjI2MzIyYzIxMDgyZmI2YWU3MjQzZTJkMDZjMWNhNzVjZTAxZDA5MDQ5YWI5ODQyNjcwNzdiMzY2Mzk3OWFiYWZkZWZlZjllMjNjMzRlOThlZDkyZjM2NDM4N2M1ZjZhYmIzZjk1YzBjYjE3MGE4ZTJhODJhODcxYyJ9XX0="}]},"signature":{"type":"SHA3MerkleProof","targetHash":"a2293d413b9ceb67221df05a47d8bb44d54c1f147bd0a599d94da99d07f182fd","proof":[],"merkleRoot":"a2293d413b9ceb67221df05a47d8bb44d54c1f147bd0a599d94da99d07f182fd"}}
```

Comment: Please don't manually create your own JSON strings. Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead